Wiring a Single Pole Switch with 3 cables coming into box
Trying to wire a single-pole light switch and I have 3 sets of wires coming into the box (3 black, 3 white, 3 copper).
The copper ground wires are bound together but not sure how to attach the 3 black & 3 white wires.
It appears that one of the wires come from underneath the box from a nearby receptacle.  The other 2 wires go out the top of the box.
Any advice is appreciated.

you need to bit more work, find out if one of the black is permanently hot and connect to the switch. now find out which one of the remming black does what. the neutrals are not switched

Can you add a picture of the box where you want to place the switch and indicate which wires are hot (carrying line voltage)? Also indicate if there is anything (other lights; receptacles) on the circuit that is not working.

"Copper" is not neutral, it's ground.  White is typically neutral.

Is this a new switch or a replacement switch?
